# Can't read redis python client messages from redis-cli

Tags: python, redis

I am publishing messages to a Redis broker from Python.

Subscribe to "test_key" from redis-cli:

```
# Run the server
redis-server

# In new instance, run the cli
redis-cli

# Subscribe to the key
SUBSCRIBE test_key
```

In Python:

version of the redis client: redis==3.4.1

```py
import redis
redis_connection = redis.Redis()  # basic conf: localhost, port 6379, db 0
redis_connection.set("test_key", "Hello Redis")

# If I run redis_connection.get("test_key")
b'Hello Redis'
```

**My question**: While I can get my messages from the Python environment, absolutely no messages are showing in the redis-cli terminal. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `SUBSCRIBE` works with `PUBLISH` not `SET`.

Comment: And it works ! Thanks a lot. What is the difference between publish and set?

Comment: You will find that in the documentation in more details than we could give here.